# How to deal with massive concurrent transactions in databases

Tags: database, concurrency, transactions

This is a question I was thinking about on the database developer side:
How do you deal with many concurrent access/modifications to the data?

I mean, an application with thousand of access/modifications to the same data at the same time.

I know the basics of ACID and transaction (like using a commit system and rollback systems), but how such a database would be implemented? Normally, the transaction should only fail, but if there is thousand of transaction failing, I feel like it's a waste of time... So how are such systems implemented ?

Comment: look up multi-version concurrency control

Comment: Thanks ! seems like a good start :)